# How to design the interfaces between the components of a schematic block diagram?

Tags: systems-engineering, systems-design

From the diagram below, the interface between the "Intert Gas Pressurization Subsystem" and the "Oxidizer Storage Subsystem" is labelled as "Inert Gas Pressurant". This tells us that there will be "Inert Gas Pressurant" going from one to the other but does not tell us how that transfer will be achieved, how can we find out how the interface will be achieved?

[image]

References:

1. [Systems Engineering Fundamentals - Page 62](https://acqnotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/DAU-Systems-Engineering-Fundamentals.pdf)

Comment: You need to get the diagrams at the next level down. Find the diagram or other documentation for the "Inert Gas Pressurization System".

Comment: you could take an approach similar to a wiring diagram where cable (length, part number, etc) and connector specs are annotated on each connection.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson This is the only example diagram provided but, if we look at the Oxidizer Storage Subsystem there could be some sort of Oxidizer Nozzle inside of it which provides the fuel. And the Solenoid Valve could again have an Oxidizer nozzle to allow the Oxidizer to enter the Solenoid Valve.
I see how this helps but still, where is the pipe that would carry the oxizider defined?

Comment: You are looking for detailed designs in a document catering to project management.  Seems like you should be looking for Moon Station Rendezvous Vehicle documents.

Comment: @RichardBamford Would you like us to suggest what the design of these two subsystems and their interface should be, or is this an academic exercise in systems engineering?  I am a little bit familiar with systems engineering terms, but I am v familiar with rocket and spacecraft design.  I would suggest that the interface medium between these two 'subsystems' is simply a pipe or tube, since the rest of the interface is perhaps captured by the subsystem diagram.  The rest of the text in this diagram contains 'information' and the gas is certainly a sensible 'signal' for the fuel and ox tanks.